# 2-line WearableListView not working properly

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, wear-os

I'm trying to display a 2-line list view within my wearable app like the one in the photo below (without the icons) but for some reason it's not working as expected. I believe the problem lies with the following line of code:

```
ListViewItem androiders = new ListViewItem();
```

Something needs to go inbetween the parentheses because when nothing is there, the following error is returned.

> ListViewItem (String) in ListViewItem cannot be applied to ()

I tried some options but none of them worked.

**Option A**

```
ListViewItem androiders = new ListViewItem("");
```

[image]

**Option B**

```
ListViewItem androiders = new ListViewItem("hello world");
```

[image]

Does anyone know what should be placed between the parentheses in order to resolve this issue?

**Expected result**
[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements WearableListView.ClickListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialize();
    }

    List<ListViewItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private void initialize() {
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.versions_array);
        String[] itemDescriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.years_array);
        for (int n = 0; n < items.length; n++){
            ListViewItem androiders = new ListViewItem(?);
            androiders.setID();
            androiders.setVersion(items[n]);
            androiders.setYear(itemDescriptions[n]);
            list.add(androiders);
        }

        WearableListView wearableListView = (WearableListView) findViewById(R.id.wearable_list_view);
        ListViewAdapter mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        wearableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        wearableListView.setClickListener(this);
        wearableListView.addOnScrollListener(mOnScrollListener);
    }
}
```

**ListViewItem.java**

```
public class ListViewItem {

    public String text0;
    public String text1;
    private String version;
    private String year;

    public ListViewItem(String text) {
        this.text0 = text;
        this.text1 = text;
    }

    public String getVersion(){
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version){
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year){
        this.year = year;
    }

    private int _id;
    public void getID(int _id){
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public int setID(){
        return _id;
    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!--Versions strings-->
    <string name="jellybean">Jelly Bean</string>
    <string name="kitkat">KitKat</string>
    <string name="lollipop">Lollipop</string>
    <string name="marshmallow">Marshmallow</string>
    <string name="nougat">Nougat</string>

    <!--Years strings-->
    <string name="released_2012">Released: 2012</string>
    <string name="released_2013">Released: 2013</string>
    <string name="released_2014">Released: 2014</string>
    <string name="released_2015">Released: 2015</string>
    <string name="released_2016">Released: 2016</string>

    <!--Versions array-->
    <string-array name="versions_array">
        //item 1    <item>@string/jellybean</item>
        //item 2    <item>@string/kitkat</item>
        //item 3    <item>@string/lollipop</item>
        //item 4    <item>@string/marshmallow</item>
        //item 5    <item>@string/nougat</item>
    </string-array>

    <!--Years array-->
    <string-array name="years_array">
        //item 1    <item>@string/released_2012</item>
        //item 2    <item>@string/released_2013</item>
        //item 3    <item>@string/released_2014</item>
        //item 4    <item>@string/released_2015</item>
        //item 5    <item>@string/released_2016</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at your constructor in 'ListViewItem.java', should be obvious what has been set. `text0` and `text1` have been set, then your list adapter is using those values in the list.

Comment: hello world is appearing as expected

 public ListViewItem(String text) {
        this.text0 = text;
        this.text1 = text;
    }

hello world is text 0 and 1

Comment: I already know about 'hello world' but I wasn't referring to that. I was referring to the items in my arrays as they are not appearing as expected. Is the code in your previous comment a suggestion?